# show progressbar in td of the table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Following is my code of progressbar.

```
success: function (response) {
    var abc = response;
    if (response != "Error!") {
        $({ counter: 1 }).animate({ counter: (response + 1) },
            {
                step: function () {

                    $('.outerDiv').text(Math.ceil(this.counter) + '% Success');
                    $('.outerDiv').css({ 'color': 'green', 'font-size': '100%' });
                    $('.innerDiv').progressbar({
                        value: response,
                    })
                }
            })
    }
    else {
        $('.innerDiv').each(function () { $(this).text(response); })
        $('.innerDiv').css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '110%', 'text-align': 'left' });
    }
}
```

I want to show progress bar in respective `tds`. I have `buttons` in each row, and progress bar should display in that row only. Problem is, if I declare innerDiv and outerDiv with ids, then progressbar shows up in only one row, as id is unique element in html. And if I declare class for innerDiv and outerDiv , then progressbar shows up in all rows of the table which is not the desired output. It must e displayed in one row only. I used innertext and innerhtml but it shows errors in browser that innertext is not defined. Please guide.

HTML code

```
          <td width="350px">
                        <div class="innerDiv"   style=" height:18px;text-align:center; width:150px;  color:black">
                        </div>
                        <div class="outerDiv" style="height:18px;width:100px;">
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

table html code

```
                       @for (int i = 0; i < Model.mdl_Playlists.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td id="playlistid">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.mdl_Playlists[i].playlist_id)
                    </td>
                    <td id="playlistname">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.mdl_Playlists[i].playlist_name)
                    </td>
                    <td id="playlistid">
                        <a href="#demo11" data-toggle="collapse" class="sched"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"> </span> </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnGet" class="sendbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"> </span> </button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.mdl_Playlists[i].created_date)
                    </td>
                    <td id="state" class="progressTD" width="350px">

                        <div  class="innerDiv" style=" height:18px;text-align:center; width:150px;  color:black">
                        </div>
                        <div  class="outerDiv" style="height:18px;width:100px;">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

Comment: Maybe you can set an id on the td and pass it in the click of the button, in order to point directly to the id instead of to the class

Comment: @Luciano can u show it by example

Comment: Ok, can you edit the question by adding the html code and the full click button code? I will change it as described

Comment: Check the answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1**
Compared to the for loop used, just make the id of the td unique. In the example below I assumed that playlist_id is unique and I used it to compose the id, alternatively you can also use the variable i.

**HTML**

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.mdl_Playlists.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td id="playlistid">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.mdl_Playlists[i].playlist_id)
            </td>
            <td id="playlistname">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.mdl_Playlists[i].playlist_name)
            </td>
            <td id="playlistid">
                <a href="#demo11" data-toggle="collapse" class="sched"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"> </span> </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="btnGet" class="sendbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"> </span> </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.mdl_Playlists[i].created_date)
            </td>
            <td id="@("playList" + Model.mdl_Playlists[i].playlist_id)" class="progressTD" width="350px">

                <div  class="innerDiv" style=" height:18px;text-align:center; width:150px;  color:black">
                </div>
                <div  class="outerDiv" style="height:18px;width:100px;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

---

I did a live demo with fake data (without your full code I can't be more precise):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2plenp

These are the key points:

1. set id to td on the progress bar
2. I used the progressTD class to retrieve the id to use in the click on the button (it may not be necessary in your scenario)
3. clicking the button retrieves the ID and passes it to the progress bar function
4. in the progress bar function I used the id to point to the correct td ($("#" + id + " .innerDiv"))

The code:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="350px" id="row1" class="progressTD">
            <div class="innerDiv" style=" height:18px;text-align:center; width:150px;  color:black">
            </div>
            <div class="outerDiv" style="height:18px;width:100px;">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnGet1" class="sendbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"> </span> btn1</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="350px" id="row2" class="progressTD">
            <div class="innerDiv" style=" height:18px;text-align:center; width:150px;  color:black">
            </div>
            <div class="outerDiv" style="height:18px;width:100px;">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnGet2" class="sendbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"> </span> btn2</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="350px" id="row3" class="progressTD">
            <div class="innerDiv" style=" height:18px;text-align:center; width:150px;  color:black">
            </div>
            <div class="outerDiv" style="height:18px;width:100px;">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnGet2" class="sendbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"> </span> btn3</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Button Click**

```
$(function() {
  $(".sendbtn").click(function() {
    const rowID = $(this)
      .closest("tr")
      .find(".progressTD:first")
      .attr("id");

    performProgressBar(rowID, "");
  });
});
```

**Progress Bar Functions**

```
function performProgressBar(id, response) {
  var abc = response;
  if (response != "Error!") {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      progressBar(id, i);
    }
  } else {
    $("#" + id + " .innerDiv").each(function() {
      $(this).text(response);
    });
    $("#" + id + " .innerDiv").css({
      color: "red",
      "font-size": "110%",
      "text-align": "left"
    });
  }
}

function progressBar(id, progressValue) {
  $({ counter: 1 }).animate(
    { counter: progressValue + 1 },
    {
      step: function() {
        $("#" + id + " .outerDiv").text(Math.ceil(this.counter) + "% Success");
        $("#" + id + " .outerDiv").css({ color: "green", "font-size": "100%" });
        $("#" + id + " .innerDiv").progressbar({
          value: progressValue
        });
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working as expected. I can see progressbar in all the three rows.

Comment: In my example, only the progress bar corresponding to the button you click is loaded. Tell me what you expected to see.

Comment: Hi @Luciano , in your live demo, I can not see progressbar in all three rows. I can see only success label and percentage. I want to see green progressbar in respected innerdiv. Can you help me on that

Comment: In my example the graphic part is missing, I have not loaded the bootstrap libraries and the style sheets of the progress bar, for this you only find the text. Look here for graphic examples of the progress bar: https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: alright @Luciano. Still, when I implemented your code at my side, the progressbar and success label is shown in all the three tds. It is maybe because my td is in for loop. I will update my code again and show it to you.

Comment: Please check my updated table html code and let me know the changes I have to make in jquery

Comment: please guide further. @Luciano

Comment: No it doesn't change. The Jquery is based on the class.

Comment: Hey @Luciano , , it is working like charm! Making an id unique helped me. Thanks a lot for your valuable guidance!